# Meteor Javascript File Concatenation

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have read somewhere that Meteor itself concatenates multiple files into one file and even minifies it.

I am not too concerned about magnification since I believe Meteor minifies all of the files automatically at the end.

I however have one huge .js file that I wanna split into multiple files and concatenate in the proper order for them to work.

I don't know how to go about this but I was wondering if I can do it the same way as Meteor has done.

How can this be done?

e.g.
file1.js
has

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

I would like to have

> file1.js -> first section of javascript codes file2.js -> second section of javascript codes file3.js -> third section of javascript codes file4.js -> fourth section of javascript codes

and then combine all 4 files into one or include one after another....

Is this possible in Meteor JS?

Comment: Is `line1` a string or a JavaScript object?

Comment: all are javascript code.....

Comment: Have not tried meteor. Have you tried using `import`, `export`, or parsing the text of the file for the first line?

Comment: What version of Meteor do you use? Is this huge JS file for client or server?

Comment: Meteor 1.5.2.1 and the huge file is in the client...thanks

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: you don't want to do this _in_ Meteor, you want to do this _like in_ Meteor?

Comment: I would like to do it in my Meteor app...whether or not it is like Meteor is secondary...I primarily would just like to achieve the end goal no matter the method....the file is too huge and I waste time scrolling to find the right section to edit....